# How do I make pinpoints in an embedded Google Maps lead to other pages on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

first time posting and I really appreciate any potential help. I would like to make it so that you can click on one of many pinpoints and have it take you to another page on the site. I don't even know how to locate the pinpoints inside the maps embed to link it with an anchor tag. Is this something doable with just HTML? Would it involve JS?

Here's an example Google Maps embed with multiple pinpoints.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1h8QJ9YZV9_q8YJgP7QF1t2njZhVK5kxL&ehbc=2E312F" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: There is no example in your question, please check. Please put the code you have tried already into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you studied Google’s documentation on this? They give clear examples and yes you will find quite a bit if JS is involved.